# How to detect if NSURLConnection's sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error: ended up being timed out or other error

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I use `NSURLConnection's` `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` method (in a separate `NSOperation` thread) to connect to external server to retreive data. How do I know if the operation ended timed out, or some other network error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there was an error, the error parameter will be non-nil when `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` returns.

You can retrieve the error code by checking the value returned by `[NSError code]`. The error code for time out is `NSURLErrorTimedOut`.

For instance:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]

if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
// Handle time out here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this `extension`:

```
extension Error {

    var isConnectivityError: Bool {
        guard _domain == NSURLErrorDomain else { return false }

        let connectivityErrors = [NSURLErrorTimedOut,
                                  NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet,
                                  NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost,
                                  NSURLErrorCannotConnectToHost]

        return connectivityErrors.contains(_code)
    }
}
```

You can check in doc for other errors in `NSURLError` domain to expand your `connectivityErrors` array.

Answer (score -1):

You may present an alert to the user and pass the error parameter in `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` to the alert's message.

the code will be something like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req returningResponse: &response error: &error];

if (error)
{
UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Hope it helps!!